# Interrupts execution context

Tags: interrupt, interrupt-handling

I'm trying to figure out this basic scenario:
Suppose my cpu received an exception or an interrupt. What I do know, is that the cpu starts to perform an interrupt service routine (looks at the idtr register to locate the idt table, and goes to the appropriate entry to receive the isr address), but in what context is the code running?

Meaning if I have a thread currently running and generating an interrupt of some sort, in which context will the isr run, in the initial process that "holds" the thread, or in some other magical thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, which raises a few different issues.

The first is that interrupts don’t actually run inside of any thread from the CPU’s perspective.  Indeed, the CPU itself is barely aware of threads; it may know a bit more if it has hyper threading or some similar technology, but a thread is really an operating system thing (or, sometimes, an application thing).

The second is that ISRs (Interrupt Service Routines) generally run at some elevated privilege level; you don’t really say which processor family you’re talking about, so it’s difficult to be specific, but modern processors normally have at least one special mode that they enter for handling interrupts — often with its own register bank.  One might also ask, as part of your question, whose page table is active during an interrupt?

Third is the question of whose memory map ISRs have when they are entered.  The answer, again, is going to be highly processor specific; it’s possible to imagine architectures that disable paging on ISR entry, other architectures that switch automatically to an interrupt page table, and (probably the most common approach) those that decide not to bother doing anything about the page table when entering an ISR.

The fourth is that some *operating systems* have policies of their own on these kinds of things.  A common approach on modern operating systems is to make ISRs themselves as short as possible, and where any significant work needs to be done, convert the interrupt into some kind of event that can be handled by a kernel thread (or even, potentially, by a user thread).  In this kind of system, the code that actually handles an interrupt may well be running in a specific thread, though it probably isn’t actually an interrupt service routine at that point.

Summary:

- ISRs themselves don’t *really* run in the context of any given thread.
- ISRs *may* run with the page table of the interrupted thread (depends on architecture).
- ISRs *may* start with a copy of that thread’s registers (depends on architecture).
- In modern systems, ISRs commonly try to schedule an event and then exit quickly.  That event might be handled by a specific thread (e.g. for processor exceptions, it’s usually delivered as a signal or Structured Exception or similar to the thread that caused it); or by a pool of threads (e.g. to service I/O in the kernel).

If you’re interested in the specifics for x86 (I guess you are, as you use some Intel specific terms in your question), you need to look at the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), volume 3B, *and* you’ll need to look at the operating system documentation.  x86 is a very complicated architecture compared to some others — for instance, it can *optionally* perform a task switch on interrupt delivery (if you put a “task gate” in the IDT), in which case it will certainly have its own set of registers and quite possibly its own page table; even if this feature is used by a given operating system, there is no guarantee that x86 tasks map straightforwardly (or at all) to operating system processes and/or threads.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great answer. Indeed I neglected to specify that my interest was X86. As a follow up question, it now accord to me, where does the state of the initial thread gets saved? Onto its stack, in some dedicated ram?

Comment: @rig Traditionally, on the stack.  The slight niggle is that often the stack in question will be a different one, though it *might* not be, depending on whether you’re already at the relevant privilege level.  x86 is a traditional architecture in this respect.  Some other architectures instead switch to a secondary register bank, which leaves you as the ISR author to decide if you want or need to save the state to RAM.